# iptables not filtering bridged traffic

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, bridge

I have a linux host running 3.10 kernel with two bridged interfaces: eth0 & eth1 as brid00 with no IP.

Bridge works fine, but now I want to filter some of the traffic going through the bridge, but iptables' rules are not firing.

I have enabled `net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` (all traffic is IPv4) and `net.ipv4.ip_forward` and I'm using *physdev* module for matching.

For example, trying to block all ICMP requests with

`iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 --physdev-out eth1 -j DROP`

has no effect. Any clue on whats happening? I think this kind of filtering was possible without using ebtables (My future plan is use nfqueue in some advanced filtering so I need iptables to fire the rules with the bridge traffic).

Comment: Tested on a machine running kernel 4.10 and the rules work fine, what am I missing? Any major change on how packets are routed between kernel 3.x and 4.x?

Comment: I'm really surprised if this worked on 4.10 with bridged traffic; to my knowledge, bridged traffic is all on L2, so the L3 iptables hooks are never called. Just use `ebtables`.

Comment: It's an exception, if you enable the parameter net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables, the traffic will call iptables. No way of making it work on kernel 3.10, looks like a bug because docs says it should. Works fine also in kernel 4.9 and 4.14. BTW, br_netfilter is a separated module in 4.x, you have to modprobe it to enable the functionality

Comment: Make that comment an answer? (You can answer your own questions).

Comment: maybe because you are writing icmp instead of igmp ?

Comment: @ibrahim what do you mean? pings are icmp traffic, not igmp, I think you are confusing both protocols.

Comment: @vktr In the question you stated "trying to block all IGMP requests with". That's why I thought maybe you want to block IGMP. If this is not the case, you can ignore me.

Comment: @ibrahim ops, that was a typo, my fault. Editted for future viewers (I was testing pinging the other machine, so is ICMP traffic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considered a bug in kernel 3.10 (maybe only in my architecture, arm64). Works fine in 4.x kernels, tested in few of them. According to kernel diagrams and docs routing is the same between kernels 3.x & 4.x and should work in both, but it doesn't.

br_netfilter is a separate module in kernel 4.x, you have to `modprobe br_netfilter` to enable functionality.